# Assembled redboard PTH kit, when I turn it on the led flashes increasingly fast and stops

Tags: hardware

I assembled the following sparkfun redboard: **https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10776**

When I plug the board in it start to blink but increasingly fast until the LED stops.

I'm very new to this and not sure what could be the issue or what to look. Any tips on how to debut this?

Here are images of the assembled board:
[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Comment: Adding a Picture of *your* board that you put together would be useful for others to see if there is a problem. Also compare yours to the sparkfuns one.

Comment: Just added images of the assembled board

Answer (score 1):

The board seems to be working. After I plugged in an ftdi connector (adafruit FTDI friend) and uploaded blink to it, it started blinking every second instead of really fast.

The documentation was a bit confusing as it implied that blink was pre-loaded on the device but instead it would just blink extremely fast until it went all the way on and then turn off the green led.